# Ruby: blank? without Rails

Tags: ruby

I want to have this test:

```
if (line.blank?) do_stuff
```

...but I'm in straight ruby, not rails. What's the accepted idiom for accomplishing the same effect?

I'm doing this for a string, where testing for .empty? is not the same as testing for .blank? (An all whitespace string is not empty, but is blank.)

Comment: Have a look at the source. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. Found it under String there. Would you mind adding this answer below, so I can accept it? (Unfortunately both answers offered so far are not correct, in the context of a string, where a line with all whitespace still tests as non-empty.) The rails definition is just:   def blank?
    self !~ /[^[:space:]]/
  end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb)

```
line !~ /[^[:space:]]/
```

Comment: Is `/[^[:space:]]/` different from `/\S/`? I am wondering why Rails did it with the former way.

Comment: @sawa The [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) mention it including `[:blank:]` which is a check for tab characters. It also contains checks for newlines and carriage returns. Perhaps this is why.

Comment: That is the same for `/\s/`.

Comment: @sawa `/\s/` is strictly equivalent to `/[ \t\r\n\f]/`, whereas the [POSIX bracket expression](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Character+Classes) `/[[:space:]]/ ` matches any [Unicode whitespace character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode).

Answer (score 9):

This is possible:

```
line.to_s.strip.empty?
```

Answer (score 9):

`blank?` is not only defined in String, it's also part of Nil, because it is a two-fold test. It checks to see if a variable is either `nil?` or `empty?`/white space.

You can't ask a string if it's nil because it doesn't have a `nil?` method, but you can ask a Nil if it's `nil?`.

Active Support has core-extensions available, which let us cherry-pick the needed functionality and include the necessary methods. For `blank?` you can do:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
```

See the [`blank?`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark) for more information and read the entire document to see what else is available. Using Active Support this way removes the need to load all of AS yet get features that are useful.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @sawa's answer

```
pry(main)> Benchmark.ips do |x|
pry(main)*   x.report("strip") { "  ".strip.empty? }
pry(main)*   x.report("regex") { "  " !~ /\S/ }
pry(main)*   x.compare!
pry(main)* end
Warming up --------------------------------------
               strip   199.937k i/100ms
               regex   120.402k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
               strip      4.205M (± 3.6%) i/s -     21.193M in   5.047231s
               regex      2.019M (± 3.7%) i/s -     10.114M in   5.017202s

Comparison:
               strip:  4204798.7 i/s
               regex:  2018957.6 i/s - 2.08x  slower
```

so `if line.to_s.strip.empty?` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

`blank?` essentially just checks `empty? || nil?`. So you can either make the blank method yourself, or check both of them in your conditionals.

Comment: From the [doc](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F), `blank?` returns `true` for a whitespace string, which is not the case for `empty? || nil?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if line.empty? || line.nil?
```

You can wrap it in a *blank?* method in  your *line* class

Comment: This doesn't work for whitespace strings. See my comment above.