# Ruby's `.present?` without Rails?

Tags: ruby, daemon, standard-library, daemons, ruby-daemons

I'm developing a "Rails-less" Ruby daemon for automation (although in theory it runs within a Rails directory). For general purposes and the principle of the matter, I would like to find the (most) "native"/common way to utilize a Ruby version of `.present?`/`.blank?`/`.empty?`/`.nil?` to identify if an array or a (hash) value exists and is not empty (i.e., `[]` or `{}`).

From what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397316/ruby-blank-without-rails?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (e.g., Stack Overflow) and tested, all of these functions appear to be Rails-specific methods, part of ActiveSupport(?).

Coming from other web/interpreter languages (PHP, Python, JS, etc.), this is a general logic function most languages (with arrays, which are most) have this functionality built in one way or another (e.g., PHP's `isset( ... )` or JavaScript's `.length`).

I understand there are RegEx workarounds for `.blank?`, but `.present?` seems it would require exception handling to identify if it's "present"). I'm having a hard time believing it doesn't exist, but there's little talk about Ruby without Rails' involvement.

Comment: `present?`, `blank?`, `empty?`, and `nil?` are quite different. What do you really need / want? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Do ruby's built-in methods like `.empty?`, `.nil?`, `.zero?`, etc really not solve your problem? Do you really need to pull `ActiveSupport` into your project as a dependency? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Active Support` is broken in small pieces so that you can load just what you need. For `.blank?` and `.present?` methods it would be enough to require:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb'
```

[As docs say](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#stand-alone-active-support).

[Object#nil?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F) , [Array#empty?](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#stand-alone-active-support) and [Hash#empty?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-empty-3F) already defined so you dont need anything to `require` to use those.

Make sure `active_support` gem installed in your system

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveSupport without including all rails in your app, that's actually quite common.

`nil?` and `empty?` are defined in the standard library.

E.g., [`String#empty?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-empty-3F) is simply testing if the length is 0.

To use active support, just install the gem or add it to your gemfile then:

```
require 'active_support'
```

The [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) also states you can cherry pick the core extensions you want:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
```